# problem in css when write in css nothing has changed

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem with CSS, I am linking it and changing the body color, and nothing has changed, and when I open a view page source, the modification appears on the CSS page already?

Comment: pls share your code

Comment: In case it works fine on hard refresh (CTRL+F5), than it is just your browser cache...

Comment: @Abdelrahman Shahin: Hey sounds like you are linking the CSS incorrectly . Please post  the code to how you are linking it and also is your CSS in a folder called CSS?

Comment: <!---css---->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <!---------->

Comment: Is your style.css in same folder as your html file?

Comment: no,, the folder named CSS But I deleted the file and came out with the CSS next to it index.php

Comment: body {
    background-color: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you type `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">` in the `<head>` of your html document, the code you tope is correct, both documents are in the same file and that you save your CSS file before you check your result.
If you want a better answer, post your code.

Comment: <!---css---->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
     <!---------->

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShahin You don't need <!---css---> and <!---------->.